# odd behavior of UIPickerView on ActionSheet

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipickerview, uitoolbar, uiactionsheet

```
- (void) actionsheetstart
{
    actionSheet=[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 32)];
    [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];
    pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancel_clicked:)];
    [barItems addObject:cancelBtn];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(done_clicked:)];
    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];
    [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
    [actionSheet addSubview:pickerToolbar];

    UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    picker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 216);
    picker.delegate  = self;
    picker.dataSource = self;
    picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [actionSheet addSubview:picker];
}

-(void)done_clicked:(id)sender
{
    [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
-(void)cancel_clicked:(id)sender
{
    [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

for some reason, the actionsheet is fine, but the UIPickerView and the UIToolBar gone crazy.
I've try to set the frame to -px but without any success. what seems to be the problem?

Thanks alot.

[image: dismissing pickerview]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't insert `UIPickerView` inside `UIActionSheet`, you won't get correct behaviour this way. My solution:

1. Subclass `UIButton`, implement method `canBecomeFirstResponder:`, return `YES`.
2. Implement `inputView` method in your subclassed `UIButton`, return `UIPickerView`.
3. Optionally, implement `inputAccessoryView` method in your subclassed button to return toolbar above your picker.
4. Make your button `becomeFirstResponder:` when tapped.

Voila, you have picker shown modally like a keyboard when button is tapped.

**EDIT:**

MyButton.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyButton : UIButton

@end
```

MyButton.m

```
#import "MyButton.h"

@implementation MyButton {
    UIDatePicker *_pv;
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - Picker

- (UIView *)inputView {
    // set up your UIPickerView here
    _pv = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    [_pv setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime];
    [_pv setMinuteInterval:30];
    return _pv;
}

- (UIView *)inputAccessoryView {
    // set up your toolbar here
    UIToolbar *tb = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    UIBarButtonItem *flex = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *ok = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(pick:)];
    [tb setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flex, ok, nil]];
    return tb;
}

- (void)pick:(id)sender {
    // store picker value here before closing inputView
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}
@end
```

Comment: I'm new to Obj-C and really I don't have any clue how to do it. :( but thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry I kept you waiting. See my edits above for sample implementation.